# reactjs: re-render part of the screen each time a reducer is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reactjs project and I have a screen that needs a component to display the updated reducer values each time an action fires.  I have a button click but I am not issuing a submit button but am using the onclick event which issues a dispatcher to trigger the action.  I am seeing the reducer getting updated but I am not seeing the component get updated on the screen.  How can I trigger the render method to fire after the reducer is updated?  What if I only want the component to update and not everything in the render method, in a partial page refresh sort of scenario?

Comment: Can you share your component, reducer, and action code?  It'd be a bit more helpful in answering.

Answer (score 0):

Components can only update when their props change or the state changes.

If you connect the component to the props that are being updated, it should re-render if the props change something about the component.

If the new props don't change something about the component, then there isn't anything to re-render and it won't be.

[This section from the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#react-only-updates-whats-necessary) is pretty helpful IMO!

Comment: Context is another thing that can change to cause re-render, and also you can implement a custom lifecycle method to decide when to re-render (but rarely need to).

Answer (score 0):

whenever you are dispatching to trigger the action by any event, create a variable (say loading) set it to true or false as per you need in the reducer and then you can access the props from mapStateToProps. And you will receive the props on componentWillReceiveProps method when your new data are fetched where you can conditionally check property(our case loading ) to render your desired DOM element on the browser.

Example: Alert is shown as per the error from the server.

```
// import here
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            email: {
                value:'',
                isValid:false,
                isTouched:false,
                error:'Valid Email is required'
            },
            password:{
                value:'',
                isValid:false,
                isTouched:false,
                error:'Password of at least 6 character is Required'
            },
            isFormValid: false,
            serverResp:'',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // console.log("login props", this.props)
        if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // console.log("Component will receive", nextProps);
        if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
           return this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
        //checking server error response
        if (nextProps.auth.error) {
            this.setState({ serverResp:nextProps.auth.error.message});
        }
    }
    onChange = (e) => {
        this.handleUserInput(e)
    }
    handleUserInput(e) {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        let fieldState = this.state[name];

        this.setState({[name]:{...fieldState,value:value,isTouched:true} },
            () => { this.validateField(name, value) });
        }   
    validateField(fieldName, value) {
      //validation here
    }

    validateForm() {
        this.setState({ isFormValid:this.state.email.isValid && this.state.password.isValid });


    }
    errorClass(error) {
        return (error.length === 0 ? '' : 'has-error');
    }

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.isFormValid){
            this.props.login({
                email: this.state.email.value,
                password: this.state.password.value
            });
        } else{
            let emailState = this.state.email;
            emailState = {...emailState,isTouched:true}
            let passwordState = this.state.password;
            passwordState = {...passwordState,isTouched:true}

            this.setState({email:emailState,password:passwordState});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
                <Container>
                    <Row className="justify-content-center">
                        <Col md="8">
                            <CardGroup>
                                <Card className="p-4">
                                    <CardBody>
                                    { this.state.serverResp && 
                                    <Alert color="danger">{this.state.serverResp}</Alert>
                                        }<Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                            <h1>Login</h1>
                                            <p className="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                                            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                                <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                                    <InputGroupText>
                                                        <i className="icon-user"></i>
                                                    </InputGroupText>
                                                </InputGroupAddon>
                                                <Input invalid={ this.state.email.isTouched && !this.state.email.isValid} type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email.value} placeholder="Username" onChange={this.onChange} autoComplete="username" />
                                                <FormFeedback>{this.state.email.error}</FormFeedback>
                                            </InputGroup>
                                            <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                                                <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                                    <InputGroupText>
                                                        <i className="icon-lock"></i>
                                                    </InputGroupText>
                                                </InputGroupAddon>
                                                <Input invalid={this.state.password.isTouched && !this.state.password.isValid} type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password.value} placeholder="Password" onChange={this.onChange} autoComplete="current-password" />
                                                <FormFeedback>{this.state.password.error}</FormFeedback>
                                            </InputGroup>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col xs="6">
                                                    <Button color="primary" className="px-4">Login</Button>
                                                </Col>
                                                <Link to="/forgotpassword">
                                                    <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                                                        <Button color="link" className="px-0">Forgot password?</Button>
                                                    </Col>
                                                </Link>
                                            </Row>
                                        </Form>
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                                <Card className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: '44%' }}>
                                    <CardBody className="text-center">
                                        <div>
                                            <h2>Sign up</h2>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                          labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                                            <Link to="/signup">
                                                <Button color="primary" className="mt-3" active tabIndex={-1}>Register Now!</Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                            </CardGroup>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// Login.propTypes = {
//     loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
//     auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
//     errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
// };

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.login,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        login:(userData) => login(userData,dispatch)
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```